# Does Youtube app playback not work with wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, video, youtube

On an HTC Evo with Sprint, when trying to playback a video, the Youtube app regularly (always?) reports it can't play a video when I'm connected to a reliable wifi network.  If I immediately turn off wifi and use only the Sprint network, it works fine.

Is this really the case?  If so, why?

Comment: My G1 has the same problem and my wife uses the same wifi to watch youtube on her phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation: the EVO on Sprint can playback YouTube over WiFi.  The problem is likely some domain being blocked by the hosting WiFi network which is necessary for the YouTube app.

Answer (score 2):

That must be a carrier restriction, as I am able to playback videos on my Moto DROID v1 on Verizon form the YouTube app regardless of which network I am connected to.